# OpenGL app with GLFW and GLEW crashes

Tags: opengl, glew, glfw

**The Problem:**
I tried to write a class to draw me clickable rectangles the problem is that since I started using the new OpenGL version (4.0) in the program it doesn't render and gives me the runtime error error while reading on position 0x00000000.
I'll include the code of the class as well as the main loop in the bottom.

```
GUI::GUI(std::string name, int top, int left,int heigh, int width, bool isvisible, void(_cdecl * func)())
{
    Name=name;
    Top=top;
    Left=left;
    Heigh=heigh;
    Width=width;
    BackColor = struct_RGB();
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 1.0f);
    BackDrawFunc=func;
    Visibility=isvisible;
    GuiObj = std::vector<GUIOBJ *>();

    vertices = std::vector<float>();
    vertices.clear();

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<GuiObj.size(); i++)
    {
        GuiObj[i]->addVertices();
    };

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

    // Generate 1 buffer, put the resulting identifier in vertexbuffer
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    // The following commands will talk about our 'vertexbuffer' buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(float), vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    program = LoadShaders("res/VertexShader.glsl", "res/FragmentShader.glsl");
}


void GUI::Draw()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                 // Use our shader
                glUseProgram(program);
                // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
                glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
                glVertexAttribPointer(
                        0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
                        vertices.size(),                  // size
                        GL_FLOAT,           // type
                        GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
                        0,                  // stride
                        (void*)0            // array buffer offset
                );
                // Draw the triangle !
                glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size()); // 3 indices starting at 0 -> 1 triangle
                printf("drawing\n");
                glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

}




void main()
{
    init();

    //Main Loop
        while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(Window))
        {
            if (glfwGetKey(Window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
                glfwSetWindowShouldClose(Window, GL_TRUE);

            Test->Draw();
           glfwSwapBuffers(Window);
           glfwPollEvents();
        }
    //Termination
        glfwTerminate();
}
```

EDIT:
I copied all the code in the same file the error is solved but it still doesn't render

```
#include "extincludes.h"
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

GLFWwindow* Window;

typedef unsigned int GLuint;

GLuint VertexArrayID;
GLuint VBO;
GLuint program;

GLuint LoadShaders(const char * vertex_file_path,const char * fragment_file_path){

    // Create the shaders
    GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint FragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // Read the Vertex Shader code from the file
    std::string VertexShaderCode;
    std::ifstream VertexShaderStream = std::ifstream(vertex_file_path, std::ios::in);
    if (!VertexShaderStream.is_open()) VertexShaderStream.open(vertex_file_path, std::ios::in);
    if(VertexShaderStream.is_open())
    {
        std::string Line = "";
        while(getline(VertexShaderStream, Line))
            VertexShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
        VertexShaderStream.close();
    } else
        printf("Couldn't open VertexShader");

    // Read the Fragment Shader code from the file
    std::string FragmentShaderCode;
    std::ifstream FragmentShaderStream(fragment_file_path, std::ios::in);
    if(FragmentShaderStream.is_open()){
        std::string Line = "";
        while(getline(FragmentShaderStream, Line))
            FragmentShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
        FragmentShaderStream.close();
    } else
        printf("Couldn't open FragmentShader");

    GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
    int InfoLogLength;

    // Compile Vertex Shader
    printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", vertex_file_path);
    char const * VertexSourcePointer = VertexShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, &VertexSourcePointer , NULL);
    glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);

    // Check Vertex Shader
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> VertexShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);

    // Compile Fragment Shader
    printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", fragment_file_path);
    char const * FragmentSourcePointer = FragmentShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(FragmentShaderID, 1, &FragmentSourcePointer , NULL);
    glCompileShader(FragmentShaderID);

    // Check Fragment Shader
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> FragmentShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);

    // Link the program
    fprintf(stdout, "Linking program\n");
    GLuint ProgramID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);
    glLinkProgram(ProgramID);

    // Check the program
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> ProgramErrorMessage( glm::max(InfoLogLength, int(1)) );
    glGetProgramInfoLog(ProgramID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);

    glDeleteShader(VertexShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(FragmentShaderID);

    return ProgramID;
}

void main()
{

    //GLFW
    printf("started init of GLFW \n");
    if (!glfwInit())
        printf("startup of GLFW errored \n");
    printf("started GLFW \n");
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); //excluding old openGL functionality

    Window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 768, "Simple example", NULL, NULL);
    printf("attempt to create window \n");
    if (!Window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(Window);
    printf("Init of GLFW done \n");
    //GLEW
        printf("start init of GLEW \n");
    glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
    printf("using experimental version of GLEW\n");
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
                printf("Failed to initialize GLEW\n");

        }
    printf("done with GLEW\n");

    if (glfwGetCurrentContext()!=Window)
        printf("context error");

    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);


    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);
    program = LoadShaders("res/VertexShader.glsl", "res/FragmentShader.glsl");

    std::vector<float> vertices = std::vector<float>();
    vertices.clear();

    //triangle 1
    vertices.push_back(1);
    vertices.push_back(1);

    vertices.push_back(0);
    vertices.push_back(1);

    vertices.push_back(0);
    vertices.push_back(3);
    //triangle 2
    vertices.push_back(1);
    vertices.push_back(1);

    vertices.push_back(0);
    vertices.push_back(1);

    vertices.push_back(0);
    vertices.push_back(3);

    // Generate 1 buffer, put the resulting identifier in vertexbuffer
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    // The following commands will talk about our 'vertexbuffer' buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(float), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);


    glVertexAttribPointer(
       0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
       3,                  // size
       GL_FLOAT,           // type
       GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
       0,                  // stride
       (void*)0            // array buffer offset
    );



    //Main Loop
        while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(Window))
        {
            if (glfwGetKey(Window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
                glfwSetWindowShouldClose(Window, GL_TRUE);

            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                 // Use our shader
                glUseProgram(program);
                // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
                glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);
                // Draw the triangle !
                printf("everything setup we can draw \n");
                glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size()); // 3 indices starting at 0 -> 1 triangle
                printf("drawing\n");

           glfwSwapBuffers(Window);
           glfwPollEvents();
        }
    //Termination
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glfwDestroyWindow(Window);
        glfwTerminate();
}
```

Comment: Use trace statements or a debugger to try and isolate *where* the fault occurs. That aside, try `glewExperimental = true;` prior to calling `glewInit();`

Comment: did you call `glewInit()`?

Comment: Yes I didn't added the init phase but glew is setup properly. Also the crash happends at glDrawArrays I forgot to mention it

Comment: You're not using VAOs effectively, by the way. If you used them the way they were intended, you would not have to call `glBindBuffer (...)`, `glEnableVertexAttribArray (...)` and `glVertexAttribPointer (...)` every time you did `GUI::Draw (...)`. All you would have to do is bind your VAO and draw.

Comment: Please show where your object for `GUI` is instantiated. I believe you are instantiating `GUI` before you have an OpenGL context, which would explain ***a lot***. If that constructor is called before you have a context, you are going to be sorry.

Comment: The init goes GLFW, GLEW, GUI, Main Loop

Comment: acctually i just discovered that the debug output of the init phase is broken maybe something is going wrong.... I can add the code later

Comment: Everything is working fine in init

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the error of the crash out it was just that you need three dimensions instead of one. This led to the error that the draw function was reading out of range....

Comment: It still doesn't render the quads :(